# Document response classes with Swagger and ServiceStack

Tags: api, documentation, servicestack, swagger

In the [petstore example](http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/#!/pet/getPetById_get_0) from wordnik they have provided documentation for their response classes. An example can be seen on the /pet/{petId} endpoint:

```
Pet {
    name (string, optional),
    id (integer, optional): foo,
    category (Category, optional),
    photoUrls (array[string], optional),
    tags (array[Tag], optional),
    status (string, optional) = ['available' or 'pending' or 'sold']: pet status in the store
}
```

It looks like it supports the following parameters:

- optional (flag that specifies if the property will always be in the response)
- allowed values
- description

Is there a way to accomplish this with the ServiceStack implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what the ServiceStack Swagger implementation currently supports, as of version 3.9.59:

- Optional: only nullable value types are described as optional. Other than that, there is currently no support for explicitly defining which properties in the *request/response body* are optional. For *path* or *query string* parameters, you can control optionality using [`ApiMemberAttribute`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/ServiceHost/ApiMemberAttribute.cs)
- Allowed values: enum types will automatically get a list of allowed values. For other types (e.g. a `string` property with a predefined set of values), annotate the property with the [`ApiAllowableValues`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/ServiceHost/ApiAllowableValuesAttribute.cs) attribute
- Description: use the `System.ComponentModel.Description` attribute

Make sure your request DTO implements the `IReturn<ResponseDtoType>` interface.

The following is probably the closest approximation to the Petstore example I can think of, given the current ServiceStack Swagger implementation:

```cs
public class Pet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Description("foo")]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public List<string> PhotoUrls { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    // If "Status" is implemented internally as a string
    [Description("pet status in the store")]
    [ApiAllowableValues("Status", "available", "pending", "sold")]
    public string Status1 { get; set; }

    // If you can implement "Status" as an enum, the allowable values
    // are instead automatically documented:
    [Description("pet status in the store")]
    public Statuses Status2 { get; set; }

    public enum Statuses { available, pending, sold }
}
```

The only property in that DTO that will get marked as optional is `Id`.